# Possible to increase Navigator font size?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

It's too small, barely size 8; I searched with Notepad++ for "font" and "navigator" in AppData's and Program Files' `MySQL/...` and changed all fonts to 20, no effect on Navigator or "File Edit View ...".

Can it be resized? (v8.0.21, community edition, 64-bit)

[image]

Comment: that is one of many parts that can't be changed at all by preferences. the only think i ccame up with is to change the screen to 150 %